# Using Qt Horizontalslider to change the value of a textedit

Tags: qt

I am working on a GUI using Qt 5. And I want to know how to change or set the value of a `textEdit`, which gets some double values, using an `Horizontalslider`.

I have tried to use the Signals/Slots method to connect the `Horizontalslider` to the `textEdit`, but it didn't work very well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example. Create new class `MyWindow` with next implementation:

```
#include <QSlider>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWidget>

const float MIN_VALUE = 0;
const float MAX_VALUE = 2;
const unsigned STEPS = 13;

class MyWindow : public QWidget {

    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QVBoxLayout *m_layout;
    QSlider *m_slider;
    QLineEdit *m_textEdit;

public:
    explicit MyWindow(QWidget *parent = 0): QWidget(parent)
    {
        m_layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        // Create horizontal slider and prepare it
        //   is it can change in range [MIN_VALUE; MAX_VALUE * STEPS]
        m_slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);
        m_slider->setMinimum(MIN_VALUE);
        m_slider->setMaximum(MAX_VALUE * STEPS);
        m_layout->addWidget(m_slider);

        m_textEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
        m_layout->addWidget(m_textEdit);

        this->setLayout(m_layout);
    }

    ~MyWindow(){}

    void setupWindow() {
        connect(m_slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), 
                    this, SLOT(updateTextOnSliderChange(int)));
    }

public slots:
    void updateTextOnSliderChange(int position) {
        // Calculate float position of slider
        float positionF = position / float(STEPS);
        m_textEdit->setText( QString::number(positionF, 'f', 2) );
    }
};
```

And use it from your `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mywindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyWindow *window = new MyWindow;
    window->setupWindow();
    window->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Code is pretty self-explanaining. So, main idea is to use typical slider which holds its position in `int`, set minimal and maximal position of slider, and every time you need to get sliders position in `float` -- just calculate it like `position / POINTS`.

Good luck in learning Qt!

Comment: You are welcome, hello1990! If it helps you and solves ypur problem, mark amswer as accepted.